# Python % Percent

Tags: python

I was wondering if anyone can help me understand the following Python calculation which the answer calculates into `97`:

```
100 - 25 * 3 % 4
```

I understand that the `%` sign in Python represents the remaining of an amount, however, I'm still not seeing how the answer comes out to `97`.  If someone could break the calculation down for so I understand it I would very grateful.. Thanks!

Comment: 25 * 3 is 75; 75 divided by 4 gives a remainder of 3.

Comment: Is this question related to programming?

Comment: @AnishShah he's basically asking about operator precedence / evaluation order in python. This isn't exactly a good question because it can simply be looked up in the docs and thus lacks research, but it's obviously programming-related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just to do with what is evaluated in what order by Python:

**Explanation of your sum**

`*` and `%` take precedence over `-`, so we first evaluate `25 * 3 % 4`.  `*` and `%` have the same priority and associativity from left to right, so we evaluate from left to right, starting with `25 * 3`. This yields `75`. Now we evaluate `75 % 4`, yielding `3`. Finally, `100 - 3` is `97`.

Answer (score 3):

The operators `*` and `%` are evaluated first <sup>1</sup>. Both have the *same* precedence, so they are evaluated from *left to right* <sup>2</sup>. Then the operator `-` is evaluated:

```
100 - 25 * 3 % 4
100 - 75 % 4
100 - 3
97
```

---

<sup>1: Because of operators precedence</sup>
<sup>[2:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3328359/2670792) Operator are left-associative, in other words, the two leftmost items will be operated on, then the result and the 3rd item will be operated on, so on</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Let me add brackets to make it unambigious:

```
100 - ((25 * 3) % 4)
```

First, the multiplication: `25 * 3 = 75`.

Then, the modulus: `75 % 4 = 3`.

And finally, `100 - 3 = 97`.

Answer (score 0):

So following the normal order of operations, you get:

1. `25 * 3 =` **75**
2. `75 / 4 =` 18 R **3**
3. `100 - 3 =` **97**