# Python Maths (100 - 25 * 3 % 4)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm a complete noob when it comes to programming and having an issue with python maths. If I run the following line of code, python returns 97 as the answer.

```
print 100 - 25 * 3 % 4
97
```

Why isn't it (100-25*3) = (100-75) = 25 or (75*3) = 225?

Comment: Because of [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence): 25 * 3 = 75. 75 % 4 = 3. 100 - 3 = 97.

Comment: Basic math, modulo has same precedence as multiplication and division.

Comment: * and % has the same precedence

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/3328359/6107715

Comment: 1- `*`(multi) 2- `/` (Div) 3-`+`(Add) 4-`-`(Sub) **This is mathematic rule not python rule !**

Answer (score 1):

The modulo operator ( `%` ) has the [same precedence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) as multiplication ( `*` ), so they are executed from left to right:

```
  100 - ((25 * 3) % 4)

= 100 - (75 % 4)

= 100 - 3

= 97
```

Comment: Thanks trincot. Was response on how % and * are excecuted from left to right because of having the same precedence makes everything clear.

Answer (score 1):

It's called [precedence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).

`100 - 25 * 3 % 4` is

```
100 - ((25 * 3) % 4)
100 - (75%4)
100 - 3
97
```

For the same reason `1 + 2 * 3` is

```
1 + (2 * 3)
1 + 6
7
```

and not 9.

Answer (score 1):

The modulo (`%`) operator has the same precedence as multiplication (`*`) and division (`/`). Let's interpret this expression on operator at a time:

```
print 100 - 25 * 3 % 4
print 100 - 75 % 4
print 100 - 3
print 97
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add brackets to override Python's default precedence. Therefore, the code should look more like this:

`100 - ((25 * 3) % 4)`

Hope I could help!