# how to populate a new column from conditions based on two existing columns , in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a new column based on conditions from two existing columns, but getting an error after using "np.where", is there any other way to achieve this ?

Input:

```
change1 change2
yes     yes
yes     no
no      yes
no      yes
```

Expected Output:

```
change1 change2 change3
yes      yes      ok
yes      no       not ok
no       yes      not ok
no       yes      not ok
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np



df1=pd.read_csv('test2.txt',sep='\t')
df1['change1'] = df1['change1'].astype(str)
df1['change2'] = df1['change2'].astype(str)


df['change3'] = np.where(df1['change1']=='yes' & df1['change2'] == 'yes', 'ok', 'not ok')

print(df1)
```

Error:

```
cannot compare a dtyped [object] array with a scalar of type [bool]
```

Comment: you are missing the parenthesis, this is called as [operator precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328355/python-operator-precedence): `np.where((df['change1']=='yes') & (df['change2'] == 'yes'), 'ok', 'not ok')`

Answer (score 4):

Use [`DataFrame.eq`](http://.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) and [`DataFrame.all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html). 
This will help you improve the syntax of code and avoid errors.

```
df['change3'] = np.where(df.eq('yes').all(axis=1), 'ok' , 'not ok')
#if you need select columns
#df['change3'] = np.where(df[['change1', 'change2']].eq('yes').all(axis=1),
                          'ok' , 'not ok')
```

without [`DataFrame.all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html)

```
df['change3'] = np.where((df1['change1']=='yes') & (df1['change2'] == 'yes'), 
                         'ok', 'not ok')
```

or

```
df['change3'] = np.where(df1['change1'].eq('yes') & df1['change2'].eq('yes'), 
                         'ok', 'not ok')
```

You can also use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) / [`Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html)

```
 df['change3'] = df.eq('yes').all(axis=1).map({True : 'ok' , False : 'not ok'})
#df['change3'] = df.eq('yes').all(axis=1).replace({True : 'ok' , False : 'not ok'})
```

---

```
print(df)

#   change1 change2 change3
# 0     yes     yes      ok
# 1     yes      no  not ok
# 2      no     yes  not ok
# 3      no     yes  not ok
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `DataFrame.replace` to convert to binary, then checking `all` per row:

```
df1['change3'] = np.where(df1.replace({'yes': 1, 'no': 0}).all(axis=1), 
                          'ok', 
                          'not ok')
```

Or with `replace` and `sum`:

```
df1['change3'] = np.where(df1.replace({'yes': 1, 'no': 0}).sum(axis=1).gt(1), 
                          'ok', 
                          'not ok')
```

```
  change1 change2 change3
0     yes     yes      ok
1     yes      no  not ok
2      no     yes  not ok
3      no     yes  not ok
```

Comment: I like your example with replace and sum , +1

Answer (score 2):

you can use:

```
df['change3'] = df.apply(lambda x: 'ok' if x['change1'] == x['change2'] else 'not ok', axis=1)
```

output:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-ever-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Comment: why downvoting?

Comment: agree with ansev, we shouldn't post cases of apply unless absolutely necessary. some of my early pandas code was bottle knecked massively by answers with `.apply` where it wasn't needed. Given that perhaps I should have know more about vectorisation but it's something we should steer beginners away from.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this, it's unnecessary, this answer is correct, although `apply` is not perferred. I upvoted.