# Logical & operator in python which gives Boolean value as the output

Tags: python, operators

I am learning about Python operators and following code snippet leaves a doubt.

I've learnt so far that:
AND operator which is a logical operator returns `True` if both the operands are true.

& operator which is a bitwise operator returns `1` if both the bits are 1 else `0`.

But following code snippet is little bit confusing as it seems like it checks whether the both the operands are true, but if so it should result `False`.

```
x = 4
y = -1

print("answer: ",x == y & x >=y)
```

output:

```
answer: True
```

Can someone please help me to understand the code.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The term you're looking for is operator precedence.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python operator precedence] (hint: `print("answer: ",(x == y) & (x >=y))`) (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328355/python-operator-precedence)

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because the `&` operator has a higher priority, so `y&x` evaluates first and yeilds `4`. This then evaluates true for both and returns true:

## Your Code:

```
x = 4
y = -1

print("answer: ",x == y & x >=y) # becomes 4(x) == 4(x&y) >=-1(y), so it is True
                                 # The variable is in brackets after its value
```

Output:

```
answer:  True
```

## Changed code:

```
x = 4
y = -1
print(y&x)
print("answer: ",(x == y) & (x >=y))# This should help
```

Output:

```
4
answer:  False
```

Answer (score 1):

The term you're looking for is operator precedence. Bitwise and happens before comparisons.

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/precedence-associativity

Your expression is evaluated as

```
x == (y & x) and (y & x) >= y
```

Note that the `&` operator is *bitwise* and, not logical and. You wouldn't run into this issue if you used the logical `and` because comparison precedes logical operations

Comment: Why link to someone's personal page from 2010? Is it any better than the official documentation?

Comment: That's the first link I found. I added it while I look for the official documentation page or a tutorial that's just as clear, since I'm not used to answering from my phone.

Answer (score 0):

Currently your code is first calculating (y&x) which is equal to 4 and then this is equated to x which is also 4. After that  4>=y is being finally done. which is also true. This is the reason why your output is true. Try adding brackets to do calculation according to your method.
Like here:
Instead of x == y & x >=y , this should be written (x == y) & (x >=y)).